# sed only substitutes first occurrence of string

Tags: sed

I use `sed` to create files from template files. I can't figure out, using `man sed`, why it does not change all the matched strings.

If my file (template_file.txt) contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/%SCRIPT_NAME% - Startup script for play %SCRIPT_NAME% engine
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
[...]
EOF
```

Using :

```
sed -e "s;%SCRIPT_NAME%;script_test_name;" template_file.txt > script_test_name
```

Produces (script_test_name) :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/script_test_name - Startup script for play %SCRIPT_NAME% engine
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
[...]
EOF
```

I see that for lines which have 2 times the string to replace, only the first one is replaced.

Can you give me a hint how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `s` command changes only the first occurrence unless you add the `g` (global) modifier to it.

```
sed -e "s;%SCRIPT_NAME%;script_test_name;g" template_file.txt > script_test_name
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the "g" modifier to the substitution:

```
sed -e "s;%SCRIPT_NAME%;script_test_name;g" template_file.txt > script_test_name
```

(note the last "g" in the template). This instruct `sed` to substitute all the matching texts in the line.